# How to create a new RealmObject that contains a RealmList

Tags: android, realm

I need to convert one of my model objects (which was automatically filled from Json using Retrofit) to a Realm Object.

At first, my code was `new RealmPoll()` instead of `realm.createObject(RealmPoll.class)`. (I was getting `NullPointerException` just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455819/realm-null-pointer-when-writing-to-database)) So I solved that issue. But I cannot find a way to copy a RealmList.

I can't find any examples of creating RealmObjects with RealmLists in the [official Realm website tutorial](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#creating-objects)  and the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/api/io/realm/RealmList.html) say

> Only Realm can create managed RealmLists. Managed RealmLists will
>   automatically update the content whenever the underlying Realm is
>   updated, and can only be accessed using the getter of a RealmObject.

which makes me believe it is somehow not possible? But it is a really simple task. I don't know how to interpret the docs meaning.

Is there any way possible to just convert an object (such as RetrofitPoll below) to a realm object (such as RealmPoll below) if it contains a list?

**One function that illustrates my question:**

```
private RealmPoll convertRetrofitPollToRealmPoll(Realm realm, RetrofitPoll retrofitPoll)
{
    RealmPoll realmPoll = realm.createObject(RealmPoll.class);  //<----- fixed, used to be "new RealmPoll()".

    //Convert List<Answer>
    RealmList<RealmAnswer> realmAnswers = new RealmList<RealmAnswer>();  //<----- How to do same thing here?
    for(RetrofitAnswer retrofitAnswer : retrofitPoll.getAnswers())
    {
         realmAnswers.add(convertRetrofitAnswerToRealmAnswer(retrofitAnswer));
    }
    realmPoll.setAnswers(realmAnswers);
}
```

**RetrofitPoll.java**

```
public class RetrofitPoll
{
    private List<Answer> answers;
    private String id;
    private Date startDate;
    private String title;
    private Topic topic;
}
```

**RealmPoll.java**

```
public class Poll extends RealmObject
{
    private RealmList<Answer> answers;
    private String id;
    private Date startDate;
    private String title;
    private Topic topic;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be possible to do the following

```
ObjectWithList obj = new ObjectWithList();
RealmList<Foo> list = new RealmList();
list.add(new Foo());
obj.setList(list);

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(obj); // This will do a deep copy of everything
realm.commitTransaction();
```

If you are using Retrofit to create your entire object-graph, you should be able to copy everything into Realm using just one a one-liner. If not, it is a bug.

Note this is also in the docs:

```
 * Non-managed RealmLists can be created by the user and can contain both managed and non-managed
 * RealmObjects. This is useful when dealing with JSON deserializers like GSON or other
 * frameworks that inject values into a class. Non-managed elements in this list can be added to a
 * Realm using the {@link Realm#copyToRealm(Iterable)} method.
```

Non-managed lists are created by just doing `new RealmList()` but this could probably be clearer in the docs.